# Populating column from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm going to be importing the data and I have a field that will have a 2-4 digit number.  I need to change that number to x0001 or x0200 depending if it was 1 or 200.  Whats the easiest way to do that in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Please show a few rows of sample data and how you want the data to look afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a select stmt that will add the x and format with leading 0's

```
select 'x' + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Num),4) from numbers
```

Comment: this assumes your table is named numbers, and field is named Num.

Comment: @DavidStetler I cant get this to work.  select 'x' + RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(nchar,numKey),4) from Test  gives me a column of F's and doesn't change my numKey column.

Comment: I dont think that you can convert to nchar because you are adding the 'x' character.  What happens when you execute:  select 'x' + RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,numKey),4) from Test

Comment: @DavidStetler select 'x' + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(varchar,numKey),4) from Test still just gives me a column of F's

Comment: what do you get when you execute:  select top 1 numKey from Test

Comment: I can do select 'x' + '000' +numkey from test and get the full thing but when I try to RIGHT it it doesn't work on it.

Comment: Right is pretty simple, it should work on pretty much anything.  It just grabs however many characters you specify starting from the right side.  So if my field is WTFLOL and I select RIGHT(field, 3) I will get back LOL.

Comment: it worked after I did the Right during my data move from one table to another table.